# How to prevent code from detecting and pulling patterns within words (Example: I want 'one' detected but not 'one' in the word al'one')?

Tags: r

I have this code that is meant to add highlights to some numbers in a text stored in "lines"

```
stringr::str_replace_all(lines, nums, function(x) {paste0("<<", x, ">>")})
```

where nums is the following pattern being deteced

```
nums<-(Zero|One|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six|Seven|Eight|Nine)+\\s?(Hundred|Thousand|Million|Billion|Trillion)?'
```

The problem I'm having is that the line of code above also leads to numbers embedded in words also being detected. In the following text this happens:

```
Get <<ten>> eggs. That is what is writ<<ten>>. I am <<one>> and al<<one>>.
```

when it should be:

```
Get <<ten>> eggs. That is what is written. I am <<one>> and alone.
```

I don't want to remove the question mark after the \s because I want to detect both numbers like "One" followed by no space and "One Hundred" which has a space in between.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround `(Zero|One|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six|Seven|Eight|Nine)+` with `\b`.
`\b` matches word boundaries, so this expression will newer match inside a word.